# connecting multiple iphone devices using bluetooth /peer 2 peer

Tags: ios4, bluetooth, gamekit

I started to work on a game application for iphone where minimum four player participate in this game , they will be connected via their BT.
my problem is that i got some sample code for connecting 2 device only (VIA bluetooth) but i m looking for connecting at least four devices,

any idea plz share if any tutorial or sample code, will be better for me.

Thanks,